# How do you load a specific GPU from CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I came up with this code but it's resulting in never ending bugs:

```
def get_device_via_env_variables(deterministic: bool = False, verbose: bool = True) -> torch.device:
    device: torch.device = torch.device("cpu")
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        if 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES' not in os.environ:
            device: torch.device = torch.device("cuda:0")
        else:
            gpu_idx: list[str] = os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'].split(',')
            if len(gpu_idx) == 1:
                gpu_idx: str = gpu_idx[0]
            else:
                # generate random int from 0 to len(gpu_idx) with import statement
                import random
                idx: int = random.randint(0, len(gpu_idx) - 1) if not deterministic else -1
                gpu_idx: str = gpu_idx[idx]
            device: torch.device = torch.device(f"cuda:{gpu_idx}")
    if verbose:
        print(f'{device=}')
    return device
```

I have a suspicion that the `gpu_idx` and  `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` don't actually match...I just want to load the right GPU. How do I do that?

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):aded (0.000 MB deduped)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py", line 1368, in <module>
    main_data_analyis()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py", line 1163, in main_data_analyis
    args: Namespace = load_args()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py", line 1152, in load_args
    args.meta_learner = get_maml_meta_learner(args)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/data_analysis/common.py", line 272, in get_maml_meta_learner
    base_model = load_model_ckpt(args, path_to_checkpoint=args.path_2_init_maml)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/mains/common.py", line 265, in load_model_ckpt
    base_model, _, _ = load_model_optimizer_scheduler_from_ckpt(args, path_to_checkpoint,
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/mains/common.py", line 81, in load_model_optimizer_scheduler_from_ckpt
    ckpt: dict = torch.load(path_to_checkpoint, map_location=torch.device('cuda:3'))
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 607, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 882, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 857, in persistent_load
    load_tensor(data_type, size, key, _maybe_decode_ascii(location))
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 846, in load_tensor
    loaded_storages[key] = restore_location(storage, location)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 827, in restore_location
    return default_restore_location(storage, str(map_location))
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 175, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 151, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 142, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 3 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1. Please use torch.load with map_location to map your storages to an existing device.
```

motivated by the fact that I am trying to use the remainign 40GB from my 5CNN with 256 & 512 filters but results it memory issues

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py", line 1368, in <module>
    main_data_analyis()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py", line 1213, in main_data_analyis
    stats_analysis_with_emphasis_on_effect_size(args, hist=True)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/data_analysis/stats_analysis_with_emphasis_on_effect_size.py", line 74, in stats_analysis_with_emphasis_on_effect_size
    results_usl: dict = get_episodic_accs_losses_all_splits_usl(args, args.mdl_sl, loaders)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/data_analysis/common.py", line 616, in get_episodic_accs_losses_all_splits_usl
    losses, accs = agent.get_lists_accs_losses(data, training)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/pretrain_convergence.py", line 92, in get_lists_accs_losses
    spt_embeddings_t = self.get_embedding(spt_x_t, self.base_model).detach()
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/pretrain_convergence.py", line 166, in get_embedding
    return get_embedding(x=x, base_model=base_model)
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/pretrain_convergence.py", line 267, in get_embedding
    out = base_model.model.features(x)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 443, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/mds_env_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 439, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 174.00 MiB (GPU 0; 79.20 GiB total capacity; 54.31 GiB already allocated; 22.56 MiB free; 54.61 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I want to use GPU 3 but the last error say GPU 0. What am I doing wrong?

cross: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-you-load-a-specific-gpu-from-cuda-available-devices-in-pytorch/174044

Comment: When CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set to a single integer then pytorch will only see one device and it will be `cuda:0` regardless of the value of the environment variable. Devices are always indexed starting at 0 in pytorch so for example if CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set to 2,5,7 then you should use pytorch device `cuda:0`, `cuda:1` or `cuda:2` to refer to devices 2, 5, or 7 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the index in `CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES` and the pytorch indexing don't actually correspond to each other i.e. `cuda:0` is the 1st gpu from the available devices in the list `CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES`.

jodag's comment:

> When CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set to a single integer then pytorch will only see one device and it will be cuda:0 regardless of the value of the environment variable. Devices are always indexed starting at 0 in pytorch so for example if CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set to 2,5,7 then you should use pytorch device cuda:0, cuda:1 or cuda:2 to refer to devices 2, 5, or 7 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is that you have only one GPU. As torch.cuda.device_count() says you are having only one GPU. However, you are trying to load model from the cuda:3, which isn't available. In other words, you are trying to load the model from the device, and the PyTorch is unable to find that device and throws an error.

Check that your Pytorch have the available cuda resources to where you want to load the model, or otherwise you can update the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable to match the device index.

Comment: if I have `CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES=3,4` then does `cuda:0` correspond to gpu 3 and `cuda:1` to gpu 4?